# Ordenar ao contrario com o .each

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu possuo uma tela que me lista algumas competências, elas vem do banco no seguinte formato.

[image: JSon competencias]

As duas ultimas são as pagas que são **OK** e logo após ela inicia o resto, onde **0219** é **Fevereiro/2019**, **0319** **Março/2019** e assim por diante. Porém na minha listagem eu preciso que ele exiba a próxima competência que seria **0219** e não a ultima que é **01/20** **(Janeiro/2020)**.

[image: atual]

O código que monta esses campos é este.

```
$.each(json.ext, function(k,v){
                inpsel = (parseFloat(v.valor_pago) == 0.0) 
                       ? `<td><input type="checkbox" value="`+ v.seq_movimento_cobranca +`" name="seq_movimento_cobranca[]" onclick="verificaBaixaManual()" data-vlr="`+ v.valor_devido +`"/>` +`</td>`
                       : `<td>&nbsp;</td>`;
                v.data_pagamento = (v.data_pagamento == null) ? '-' : v.data_pagamento;
                tbl += `<tr style="text-align:right" class="`+ v.tr_color +` tr-`+ v.seq_movimento_cobranca +`">`
                    + inpsel
                    + `<td>`+ v.data_vencimento +`</td>`
                    + `<td>`+ v.competencia +`</td>`
                    + `<td>`+ v.valor_devido.replace('.', ',') +`</td>`
                    + `<td>`+ v.taxa +`</td>`
                    + `<td>`+ v.data_pagamento +`</td>`
                    + `<td style="">`+ v.valor_pago.replace('.', ',') +`</td>`
                    + `</tr>`;
            });
```

Comment: Já tentou jogar os valores numa array ao invés de direto na variável tbl, inverter a ordem do array e então jogar na variável? Estou sem tempo para escrever a resposta agora, mas creio que isso solucione seu problema, se você só quiser inverter a ordem em que a tabela recebe os dados.

Comment: Creio que já consegui resolver, mas obrigado amigo.

Comment: Então seria interessante você colocar a sua solução como resposta ou então fechar a pergunta